# How to force a specific theme for a View's page?

Tags: views, theming

My View page looks rubbish in the site's custom theme so I'd like to force it to use another simpler theme.

Thanks

Comment: There are some solutions easy to find on drupal.org - what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The easiest is to use [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey):

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

You could use it to create a rule based on your view's path.

The other method uses [`hook_custom_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7).  Something like this would work.

```
function MYMODULE_custom_theme() {
  $request_path = request_path();

  if ($request_path == 'path/to/my/view/page') {
    return 'the_simple_theme_machine_name';
  }
}
```

You can also use [`views_get_page_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_page_view/7) to check the `$view->name` and `$view->current_display`, for the logic inside the hook.

Of the two solutions, using ThemeKey is best unless you are struggling with the selection rules.

Comment: MPD, thanks didn't try themekey as the custom module route seemed much more lightweight.  Worked fine.

Comment: hook_custom_theme() works well when you need to check what type of node is being edited. For creating nodes, hook_admin_paths() works because the node type is included in the path i.e. **$paths = array(
    'node/add/MY_NODE_TYPE' => FALSE,
  );
  return $paths;** 
will cause the default theme to be used instead of the admin theme (Sorry trouble with the formatting)

Answer (score 3):

For simple theme switching based on urls etc.. you could look at [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional properties exposed by other modules.

If you are using Drupal 6 and need further properties to decide, if the theme has to be switched, there is [ThemeKey Properties](https://drupal.org/project/themekey_properties)  (most of the properties are included in the Drupal 7 module)

> ThemeKey Properties provides additional properties for use with the ThemeKey module.